# CSS grid - align two rows with different number of columns

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a question related to CSS grid. Let's say I have 2 rows:

First row:

```
<div class="first-row">

  <div>
    Col 1
  </div>

  <div>
    Col 2
  </div>

  <div>
    Col 3
  </div>

  <div>
    Col 4
  </div>

</div>
```

Second row:

```
<div class="second-row">

  <div>
    <span>Under Col 1</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span>Under Col 2</span>
  </div>

  <div class"SPLIT-THIS">
    <span>Under Col 3</span>
    <span>Under Col 4</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

How can I split the last `div` element in second row so the content from the first row is perfectly aligned with content from the second one(like if they were identical rows by structure).

CCS That I used:

```
.first-row {
   grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
   grid-gap: 20px;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   text-align: center;
}

.second-row {
   grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
   grid-gap: 20px;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First option / approach :
  both container would need to have the same amount of column and same size to be matching visually.

The split element then needs to be spanning 2 columns and be itself a grid container .

```css
.first-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.second-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.SPLIT-THIS {
  grid-column: span 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

div,
.SPLIT-THIS span {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px
}
```

```html
<div class="first-row">

  <div>
    Col 1
  </div>

  <div>
    Col 2
  </div>

  <div>
    Col 3
  </div>

  <div>
    Col 4
  </div>

</div>

<div class="second-row">

  <div>
    <span>Under Col 1</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span>Under Col 2</span>
  </div>

  <div class="SPLIT-THIS">
    <span>Under Col 3</span>
    <span>Under Col </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

- Other options is to redefine the grid-column templates if you wish only 3 col

```css
.first-row {
  display:grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   text-align: center;
}

.second-row {
  display:grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 2fr ;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   text-align: center;
}
.SPLIT-THIS{
   display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(2,1fr);
}
div, .SPLIT-THIS span {box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px}
```

```html
<div class="first-row">

  <div>
    Col 1
  </div>

  <div>
    Col 2
  </div>

  <div>
    Col 3
  </div>

  <div>
    Col 4
  </div>

</div>

<div class="second-row">

  <div>
    <span>Under Col 1</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span>Under Col 2</span>
  </div>

  <div class="SPLIT-THIS">
    <span>Under Col 3</span>
    <span>Under Col </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would implement what is called 'Subgrid' or 'Grid level 2'.

While the container that has both of your initial rows inside is defined in CSS using 'display: grid;', define your 'SPLIT-THIS' with a separate 'display: grid;'.
Then, use 'grid-template-rows: 50%, 50%;' for 'SPLIT-THIS' as well.